# Where can I find details about the 'save' method used in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm not sure if this is a rails method or a ruby method but I am looking for details about what happens when you call @object.save.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-save

- `save` is a Rails method defined within the `ActiveRecord::Persistence` module. It saves the model. If the model is new, a record gets created in the database, otherwise the existing record gets updated.
- By default, `save` always run validations. If any of them fail the action is cancelled and `save` returns false. However, if you supply `:validate => false`, validations are bypassed altogether.
- There’s a series of callbacks associated with the `save` method. If any of the `before_*` callbacks return false the action is cancelled and `save` returns false.
- The `save!` (bang) method always runs validations but raises an `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid` exception upon validation failure.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I knew there were some validation problems. I was looking for the ordering of all the before_* callbacks. Thanks again.